# how to resolve NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, selenium

While running the below code getting error " NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
"

TestProductRecogic.py:

```
import unittest
from PageObject.ProductRcognic import ProductPage
import pytest


class TestProductRecognic(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self, setup):
        self.driver = setup

    def test_Product(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.recognic.ai/")

        self.ep = ProductPage(self.driver)
        self.ep.clickOnProduct()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your `setup` is returning the driver instance.

You would need to have a setup fixture which looks somewhat like this:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path) #example
    return driver

class TestProductRecognic(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self, setup):
        self.driver = setup

    def test_Product(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.recognic.ai/")

        self.ep = ProductPage(self.driver)
        self.ep.clickOnProduct()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
```